# Faster RCNN class-wise output and the number of labels

Tags: python, deep-learning, computer-vision, conv-neural-network, faster-rcnn

I am applying pretrained Faster RCNN model on my custom dataset and wonder if there are any ways that I can look at the number of labels in all output images by class.

I am refering the github below:
https://github.com/sovit-123/fastercnn-pytorch-training-pipeline

Thanks for your help!

I tried to search online but havent figured out anything useful.

[Figure 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hilnS.png)

Comment: Do you mean here?https://github.com/sovit-123/fasterrcnn-pytorch-training-pipeline/blob/main/data_configs/coco128.yaml

Comment: consider asking at https://stats.stackexchange.com

Comment: Nah I am thinking about how to see the result of Faster RCNN in terms of the number of labels by class like what is shown in the Figure 1 above